# Jekyll : Using links to internal markdown files

Tags: html, github, hyperlink, markdown, jekyll

md file with a link to `Folder/file.md`

When jekyll generates the index the link to the file is still `folder/file.md` and so doesn't connect to  the generated `file.html`. Can jekyll replace links in markdown with their corresponding html files?

I really want to to maintain my folder structure (7 or so subfolders, each with 3 markdown files).

Comment: downvoted because i couldn't understand the standalone question at all (and i'd love to be able to)!

Answer (score 9):

The answer [since December 2016](https://github.com/blog/2290-relative-links-for-github-pages) is to use the [jekyll-relative-links](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links) plugin.

It is a [white-listed plugin if you are hosting on GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/versions/) so you probably already have it.

---

If you are not using GitHub pages you will need the following installation instructions ([from the README](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links/blob/master/README.md)):

1.Add the following to your site's Gemfile:

```
gem 'jekyll-relative-links'
```

2.Add the following to your site's config file:

```
gems:
  - jekyll-relative-links
```

Comment: truly awesome! but... i wonder if there's a shorter way to do this... i mean all `.md` should have a default permalink without `.md` anyway, so `[foo](bar)` would work. and then `[[bar]]` would work too! any ideas?

Comment: Note that if you aren't using Github Pages or don't otherwise want to use a separate plugin, the `link` tag is built in, and [as of Jekyll 4.0](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#links), is even simpler to use.

Comment: @nrflaw argh, that was too long ago! sorry, don't care for this anymore. i'm still on jekyll, but only as legacy, while i migrate elsewhere... it'll soon die together with github after the microsoft eee. perhaps you'd be interested to also take many steps back and look around! (meant to reply antonio below, kept this for reference) 

Answer (score 4):

The tag you're looking for is `{% link %}` and it arrived in 2016.

If you had `{% link _funkyCollection/banjo.md %}` it would generate the right path to the output file `funkyCollection/banjo.html`, or `funkyCollection/banjo/index.html`, or whatever, wherever it ends up being.

Comment: too short version of what @vossad01 there meant on the other answer

Comment: Built-in, not a plugin. So not the same @cregox. Hence the shorter answer too.

Comment: argh, that was too long ago! sorry, don't care for this anymore. i'm still on jekyll, but only as legacy, while i migrate elsewhere... it'll soon die together with github after the microsoft eee. perhaps you'd be interested to also take many steps back and look around! 

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did to solve this problem with jekyll 3.8.5.

For link in root directory: /file.md

```
---
layout: page
title: Root File
permalink: /file/
---

This file is in root directory.
```

For link in subdirectory: /folder/file.md

```
---
layout: page
title: SubDir File
permalink: /folder/file/
---

This file is in sub-directory.
```

Now to link these file:

```
[Root File]({{site.baseurl}}/file/))

[Sub Dir File]({{site.baseurl}}/folder/file/)
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: did you even need `site.baseurl`? also, any idea if it's possible to link `[file](/file)` with some shorter "wiki" style such as `[[file]]`?

Answer (score 2):

i've written a simple plugin to solve this. put this in `_plugins/`, and make links refer to the `*.md` files (so github rendering linking works); if you build it with jekyll (when you are able to run plugins) the links are changed to `*.html`. since github doesn't run plugins, this isn't applied.

```
module ChangeLocalMdLinksToHtml
  class Generator < Jekyll::Generator
    def generate(site)
      site.pages.each { |p| rewrite_links(site, p) }
    end
    def rewrite_links(site, page)
      page.content = page.content.gsub(/(\[[^\]]*\]\([^:\)]*)\.md\)/, '\1.html)')
    end
  end
end
```

it's not perfect (i'm sure you could fool the regex) but it has been good enough for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A `Folder/file.md` page will result in creation of a `_site/Folder/file.html` page.

So when your link to this page it's `[Link to page]({{site.baseurl}}/Folder/file.html)` not `[Link to page]({{site.baseurl}}/Folder/file.md)`.

Jekyll will never rewrite `file.md` to `file.html` in url. So you have to set your links targets yourself to the resulting `page.url` which is usually a html file but can be css, je, json, ...

If you use `permalink: /folder/folder/` in any file.md, it will generate a /folder/folder/index.html file which can be reached with `[Link to page]({{site.baseurl}}/folder/folder/)`

Comment: So links will always only work as md links through github OR as html links via github pages but not both.<br> as the can't both be navigable.

Comment: Also when "jekyll build" is run I get the file generated at {root}/folder/file/index.html?

Comment: Github and Github pages are two completely separated things with differents rules.  
Github shows rendered md files but does not modify them. Github pages with Jekyll is making a build, it parses md files and generates html pages.

Comment: sounds like the exact same general idea from Ashwin's answer... and it works, @james, if you remove the `site.baseurl`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this and [written a basic Jekyll/Kramdown plugin](https://github.com/DanielRosenwasser/JekyllMarkdownLinkConverter). It's less likely to break than the regular expression approach.

As long as your link doesn't start with `http://` or something like it, and ends with `.md`, it will convert links to their lowercased and hyphenated names.

Of course, you could always modify the behavior to fit your needs.